# R - Listing the levels of factor 1 that have more than 2 levels of factor 2

Tags: r, list, factors, levels

I have a species distribution dataset based on museum collections. What I want to do is list the collection towns (factor) where more than 2 species (factor) have been collected.

Thank you!

Comment: see `tidyverse` `count()`& `filter()` function. Otherwise use `table()`or provide some reproducible data.

Answer (score 0):

Generate 30 observations from three cities, and 20 species (labelled as numbers for easy generation)

```
df <- data.frame( city=as.factor( rep(c('NY', 'CH', 'LA'),10) ),
                  species=as.factor( sample(1:20, 30, replace=T) )
                )
```

peek at the data

```
table(df$city, df$species)
```

Using **plyr**:

count observations for species in each city using ddply from plyr package, and return the observations with more than one observation

```
ddply(df, .(city), .fun=function(x){
  counts <- count(x$species)
  counts[counts$freq > 1,]
})
```

resulting in

```
  city  x freq
1   CH 10    3
2   CH 12    2
3   LA  9    2
4   NY  1    2
5   NY 13    3
```

where x is the species, and freq is the number of observations of the species in the city.

Using **dplyr**:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  select(species) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  filter(freq>1)
```